# Why do null keys in the hashmap always go to the first bucket?

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the benefit? And why do we need particular methods for nulls like `putForNullKey(V value)`, `getForNullKey()` and similar? What is the benefit?

Comment: It is not really a benefit but a "must have"; you cannot compute a `.hashCode()` for `null`; similarly, you cannot call `.equals()` on `null` either

Comment: You should ask yourself, how would you do this differently.

Comment: Now I understood. I will ask myself before next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate hashCode of a null key, so you have to put all the null keys in the same bucket. You might as well put them in the first bucket.

And you have specific methods for null keys since their logic is different than non-null keys. These methods are private anyway, so it shouldn't matter to the user of the `HashMap`. The public API is the same for null and non-null keys.